# Is there a limit to number of PubSub topics that can be subscribed to?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I have created a dataflow with ~30 pipelines all of which subscribe to their own topics on PubSub. When I try to launch, a random subscription always fails. However if I split my pipelines between several dataflows all the subscriptions are successful.

Is there a limit to the number of topics a single dataflow can sub to or the number concurrent subscription requests that can be made?

Failing job: 2016-06-03_07_27_29-2535656819775551181

One of the succesful ones: 2016-06-03_07_37_20-7740562448710226511

Comment: Any more detail on the error code/message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataflow has a known bug that causes subscription creation to be flaky; we are working on fixing it.  In the meantime, launching pipelines with fewer pubsub inputs should be less likely to exhibit the issue.

Comment: Ah thank you for the info. Do you think it might be possible to stagger the subscription process to avoid this flakiness?

Answer (score 0):

The limits of topics per project and subscriptions per project are defined [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas#other_limits). Dataflow does not enforce additional quotas; you can see details [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/quotas).